# JavaScript best practices, extending natives with *statics*

Tags: javascript, native

Some people will tell you that adding *prototypes* to JavaScript natives is evil. For example:

```
String.prototype.format = function(format, replacements) {
    ...
};
```

Now, for those that agree with that (if you don't, do not reply with answer—your opinion is N/A; this is not a discussion about prototypes), is adding *static* methods to natives equally as evil? (Hitherto and henceforth, "static" meaning simply a method whose context isn't an instance.)

For example, given that creating a `String.prototype.format` is evil, is adding it as a *static* an acceptable practice?

```
String.format = function(format, replacements) {
    ...
};
```

How is extending a native with a static method any different, concerning best-practices, than extending a native with a prototype? Either you're against extending natives in any way, or you're not—is there anyone in the camp that *static* extensions are acceptable while *prototypal* are not?

Comment: One of the main reasons is the same as with extending prototype: you extend "somebody else's object(s)". In big, long-running projects with lots of (ever-changing) people you generally want to avoid that and use clearly defined interfaces between different people's (or team's) code. Because if you don't you'll end up in purgatory, if not directly in hell :)
All the other reasons people usually give, like "there might be a function with that name in the future right there" are true but in comparison to the above negligible - as you'll find out if you ever work on such a large project. So...

Comment: ...while there are several technical answers, the most important one (from the point of view of industry, the individual small-project jQuery programmer won't care much) is one of people and management. If you don't care about that aspect you're open for a much greater variety of valid answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself why extending natives is evil.

Common reasons are

- Not future-proof, what if the standards say "There shall be a `String.format`"
- Not past-proof, adding enumerable properties to prototypes will break bad code.
- may lead to confusion as to what's common and what's standard
- may break bad-code (duck-typing, looks like a duck, quaks like a --- throws exception :()

It's simply a matter of weighing up how much you value those reasons. I only care about #1 (future-proofing).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a static method to a native Constructor will not likely have an unexpected impact on someone else's code or the time it takes to construct objects using said Constructor.

However, when you add a prototype method to a native Constrcutor, every instance (even the ones created to do operations like "test".indexOf("t")) will have the additional overhead of your method.  Iterating over object properties or testing capabilities (since we often can't judge an object by its type) gets more difficult.

Let's say you add String.prototype.forEach in your code.  That will leak into every module.  Now when some other code tests for the forEach method (thinking it's an array in a modern browser), they'll get a string instead--evil.

Comment: Why 2 points up? It was made very clear that the prototype-issue is already known!